# loading HTML data in iPhone sdk?

Tags: web-services, ios4, uiwebview, html-parsing

I want to get HTML data from a website. How can I do that? I have tried html parser but it fails (it keeps crashing my application using hpple).. so what can I do to load data from a web page like specific strings from a web page? is loadHTMLString a good choice (any tutorials on this would be help ful too)

thanks,

TC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)
For example just to load a web page you can write:

```
- (IBAction)grabURL:(id)sender
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
  ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request startSynchronous];
  NSError *error = [request error];
  if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
  }
}
```